# weird highlight for exact query with OR using query string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have some issues with highlights in elasticsearch v2.3
I could not come up with any logic that cause this problem here is two examples:

this is my query:

```
GET reports_all/all/_search
{
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "fields": [
          "text"
        ],
        "query": "(\"base of the pyramid impact assessment\" OR \"corporate human rights benchmark\")"
//      "query": "(\"corporate human rights benchmark\" OR \"base of the pyramid impact assessment\")"
      }
    },
    "highlight": {
      "pre_tags": [
        "<mark>"
      ],
      "post_tags": [
        "</mark>"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "text": {
          "number_of_fragments": 10
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0
}
```

check out the query part two exact match with OR separated. I just interchange the first and second phrase and this is the result of first one which highlights the in text which is wrong:

```
"highlight": {
  "text": [
    " organisations to launch <mark>the</mark> \n<mark>Corporate</mark> <mark>Human</mark> <mark>Rights</mark> <mark>Benchmark</mark> (CHRB), <mark>the</mark> \nworld’s first wide-scale project to",
    " taking \naction to reduce <mark>the</mark> environmental \n<mark>impact</mark> <mark>of</mark> our business and finding \nnew ways to help",
    " focuses <mark>of</mark> this is reducing <mark>the</mark> <mark>impact</mark> <mark>of</mark> \nclimate change. Aviva Investors signed <mark>the</mark> Montreal Carbon",
    " \nprogrammes in 2015\n</p>\n<p>Our 2015 reporting\nThis is <mark>the</mark> summary <mark>of</mark> our sustainable\nbusiness and corporate",
    " aim to uphold <mark>the</mark> highest ethical \nstandards in <mark>the</mark> way that we do business. \nIn 2015, 98% <mark>of</mark> Aviva",
    " costs to \nour customers\n</p>\n<p>    Reducing our\nenvironmental <mark>impact</mark>\nIn 2015 Aviva became <mark>the</mark>",
    " first insurer \nto achieve <mark>the</mark> Carbon Trust Supply Chain \nStandard, in recognition <mark>of</mark> work to measure",
    " Stonewall’s  \nTop 100 Employers list\n</p>\n<p>A principal partner  \n<mark>of</mark> <mark>the</mark> Living Wage \nFoundation",
    " take control <mark>of</mark> their finances, as\nwell as benefiting society and <mark>the</mark> environment\n</p>\n<p>• <mark>The</mark> way",
    " we help our local communities, giving\nthousands <mark>of</mark> organisations <mark>the</mark> support they need\nto make a"
  ]
}
```

},

but result of second one is fine:

```
   "highlight": {
      "text": [
        " organisations to launch the \n<mark>Corporate</mark> <mark>Human</mark> <mark>Rights</mark> <mark>Benchmark</mark> (CHRB), the \nworld’s first wide-scale project to"
      ]
    }
```

any idea what might went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what is happening, but it looks like your query is being broken down into separate words by the analyser there ES is adding an implicit AND in the query.

That is the reason for getting the `<mark>` highlight for each word separately.

If you want ES to consider `base of the pyramid impact assessment` as a single entity you can use the match_phrase query.

your query will be something like

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
      "should": [
         {
             "match_phrase": {
                "text": "base of the pyramid impact assessment"
             }},
             {
                 "match_phrase": {
                    "text": "corporate human rights benchmark"
                 }
             }
                 ],
                 "minimum_number_should_match": 1
             }
         }
```

Am not sure whether this will work. Let me know.